# Getting this output, with generators/list comprehensions?

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension, web.py

I'm having a bit of trouble with something, and I don't know how I could do it.

Well, I'm creating a dynamic form with buttons that adapts to how many files (in this case, movies) there are in a directory.

I have got this so far:

```
path="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\"  # insert the path to the directory of interest
movies = []
dirList=os.listdir(path)

for fname in dirList: # loops through directory specified
    print fname # prints file name
    movies.append(fname) # adds the file name to list

my_form = form.Form([form.Button("btn", id="btn" + movies[i], value = i, html=movies[i], class_="btn" +movies[i]) for i in range(len(movies))])
```

However, I want the list comprehension/generator to make `my_form` look something like this:

```
my_form = form.Form(
    form.Button("btn", id="btnA", value="A", html="Movie1", class_="btnA")
    form.Button("btn", id="btnB", value="B", html="Movie2", class_="btnB")
)
```

As you can see instead of the movie name being the id, it is `btnA` or `btnB`.

So how could I generate that output?

Comment: Please review your indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

buttons = [form.Button("btn", id="btn{0}".format(char), value=char, 
                       html=movie, class_="btn{0}".format(char))
           for char, movie in zip(ascii_uppercase, movies)]

my_form = form.Form(buttons)
```

This uses the letters in `string.ascii_uppercase` to label each item in `movies`.

Comment: No problem. Note that if you have more than 26 movies, `zip` will quietly provide only the first 26; you may want to consider this case and update appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the id to be btn + a letter according to the index of the movie?

you can use this code:

```
def letterForIndex(idx):
    return chr(ord('A')+idx)
```

so you would do :

```
 my_form = form.Form([form.Button("btn", id="btn" + letterForIndex(i),
 value = letterForIndex(i), html=movies[i], class_="btn" +letterForIndex(i)) for i in range(len(movies))])
```